# Нестандартный синтаксис JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я хочу отредактировать содержимое скрипта.Как это сделать?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write(unescape('%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%22%3E%0D%0A%3C%21%2D%2D%0D%0A%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%77%72%69%74%65%28%75%6E%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%27%25%33%43%25%36%34%25%36%39%25%37%36%25%32%30%25%36%31%25%36%43%25%36%39%25%36%37%25%36%45%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%36%33%25%36%35%25%36%45%25%37%34%25%36%35%25%37%32%25%32%32%25%33%45%25%33%43%25%36%31%25%32%30%25%36%38%25%37%32%25%36%35%25%36%36%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%36%38%25%37%34%25%37%34%25%37%30%25%33%41%25%32%46%25%32%46%25%36%31%25%36%39%25%37%32%25%32%44%25%37%34%25%37%36%25%32%45%25%37%32%25%37%35%25%32%46%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%37%34%25%36%39%25%37%34%25%36%43%25%36%35%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%34%31%25%33%43%25%33%45%25%34%32%25%34%30%25%33%35%25%34%32%25%34%43%25%32%30%25%33%45%25%33%44%25%33%42%25%33%30%25%33%39%25%33%44%25%32%30%25%34%32%25%33%32%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%37%34%25%36%31%25%37%32%25%36%37%25%36%35%25%37%34%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%35%46%25%36%32%25%36%43%25%36%31%25%36%45%25%36%42%25%32%32%25%33%45%25%33%43%25%36%39%25%36%44%25%36%37%25%32%30%25%37%33%25%37%32%25%36%33%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%36%38%25%37%34%25%37%34%25%37%30%25%33%41%25%32%46%25%32%46%25%36%31%25%36%39%25%37%32%25%32%44%25%37%34%25%37%36%25%32%45%25%37%32%25%37%35%25%32%46%25%36%39%25%36%44%25%36%31%25%36%37%25%36%35%25%37%33%25%32%46%25%34%32%25%36%31%25%36%45%25%36%45%25%36%35%25%37%32%25%33%36%25%33%30%25%33%30%25%37%38%25%33%33%25%33%30%25%33%30%25%32%45%25%36%37%25%36%39%25%36%36%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%36%32%25%36%46%25%37%32%25%36%34%25%36%35%25%37%32%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%33%30%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%36%31%25%36%43%25%37%34%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%34%31%25%33%43%25%33%45%25%34%32%25%34%30%25%33%35%25%34%32%25%34%43%25%32%30%25%33%45%25%33%44%25%33%42%25%33%30%25%33%39%25%33%44%25%32%30%25%34%32%25%33%32%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%32%46%25%33%45%25%33%43%25%32%46%25%36%31%25%33%45%25%33%43%25%36%35%25%36%44%25%36%32%25%36%35%25%36%34%25%32%30%25%37%33%25%37%32%25%36%33%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%36%38%25%37%34%25%37%34%25%37%30%25%33%41%25%32%46%25%32%46%25%36%36%25%37%32%25%36%35%25%36%35%25%37%33%25%37%34%25%37%32%25%36%35%25%36%31%25%36%44%25%37%34%25%37%36%25%32%45%25%37%35%25%36%33%25%36%46%25%37%41%25%32%45%25%36%45%25%36%35%25%37%34%25%32%46%25%36%43%25%36%39%25%37%36%25%36%35%25%37%30%25%36%43%25%36%31%25%37%39%25%36%35%25%37%32%25%33%32%25%32%45%25%37%33%25%37%37%25%36%36%25%33%46%25%37%33%25%37%32%25%36%33%25%33%44%25%36%38%25%37%34%25%37%34%25%37%30%25%33%41%25%32%46%25%32%46%25%33%38%25%33%30%25%32%45%25%33%37%25%33%36%25%32%45%25%33%31%25%33%37%25%33%36%25%32%45%25%33%33%25%33%39%25%33%41%25%33%38%25%33%30%25%33%38%25%33%32%25%32%46%25%37%32%25%36%35%25%36%45%25%33%32%25%32%45%25%36%36%25%36%43%25%37%36%25%32%36%25%36%31%25%36%44%25%37%30%25%33%42%25%36%44%25%36%46%25%36%34%25%36%35%25%33%44%25%36%46%25%37%36%25%36%35%25%37%32%25%36%43%25%36%31%25%37%39%25%32%36%25%36%31%25%36%44%25%37%30%25%33%42%25%37%33%25%36%33%25%36%31%25%36%43%25%36%35%25%34%44%25%36%46%25%36%34%25%36%35%25%33%44%25%37%33%25%37%34%25%37%32%25%36%35%25%37%34%25%36%33%25%36%38%25%32%36%25%36%31%25%36%44%25%37%30%25%33%42%25%36%31%25%37%35%25%37%34%25%36%46%25%37%33%25%37%34%25%36%31%25%37%32%25%37%34%25%33%44%25%37%34%25%37%32%25%37%35%25%36%35%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%37%34%25%37%39%25%37%30%25%36%35%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%36%31%25%37%30%25%37%30%25%36%43%25%36%39%25%36%33%25%36%31%25%37%34%25%36%39%25%36%46%25%36%45%25%32%46%25%37%38%25%32%44%25%37%33%25%36%38%25%36%46%25%36%33%25%36%42%25%37%37%25%36%31%25%37%36%25%36%35%25%32%44%25%36%36%25%36%43%25%36%31%25%37%33%25%36%38%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%36%31%25%36%43%25%36%43%25%36%46%25%37%37%25%36%36%25%37%35%25%36%43%25%36%43%25%37%33%25%36%33%25%37%32%25%36%35%25%36%35%25%36%45%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%37%34%25%37%32%25%37%35%25%36%35%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%37%37%25%36%44%25%36%46%25%36%34%25%36%35%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%36%46%25%37%30%25%36%31%25%37%31%25%37%35%25%36%35%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%37%37%25%36%39%25%36%34%25%37%34%25%36%38%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%33%36%25%33%30%25%33%30%25%32%32%25%32%30%25%36%38%25%36%35%25%36%39%25%36%37%25%36%38%25%37%34%25%33%44%25%32%32%25%33%34%25%33%35%25%33%30%25%32%32%25%33%45%25%33%43%25%32%46%25%36%35%25%36%44%25%36%32%25%36%35%25%36%34%25%33%45%25%33%43%25%32%46%25%36%34%25%36%39%25%37%36%25%33%45%27%29%29%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%2D%2D%3E%0D%0A%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E'));
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: >Нестандартный синтаксис JavaScript

 Это разве можно назвать "синтаксисом"? Это скорее зашифрованный текст.

Answer (score 2):

Вот, что делает этот код:

```
document.write("<div align="center"><a href="http://air-tv.ru/" title="A<>B@5BL >=;09= B2" target="_blank"><img src="http://air-tv.ru/images/Banner600x300.gif" border="0" alt="A<>B@5BL >=;09= B2" /></a><embed src="http://freestreamtv.ucoz.net/liveplayer2.swf?src=http://80.76.176.39:8082/ren2.flv&amp;mode=overlay&amp;scaleMode=stretch&amp;autostart=true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" width="600" height="450"></embed></div>");
```

Comment: Спасибо!Новый код работает!Если можно,ссылку на дешифратор.

Comment: console.log(unescape(...));

:)

Comment: Каким методом получен такой код?..

document.write("<div align="center"><a href="http://air-tv.ru/" title="A<>B@5BL >=;09= B2" target="_blank"><img src="http://air-tv.ru/images/Banner600x300.gif" border="0" alt="A<>B@5BL >=;09= B2" /></a><embed src="http://freestreamtv.ucoz.net/liveplayer2.swf?src=http://80.76.176.39:8082/ren2.flv&amp;mode=overlay&amp;scaleMode=stretch&amp;autostart=true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" width="600" height="450"></embed></div>");

Желательно дешифратор или раскодировщик.

Comment: Я же написал. выведите куда то 

`unescape('тот текст что в примере выше')`

затем снова unescape того что выведет и вы получите исходный текст что приведен выше.

Answer (score 0):

Символ начинается с `%`, который надо игнорировать, потом идут 2 шестнадцатеричные цифры, обозначающие номер символа. Программа для расшифровки очень простая.

Answer (score 0):

[escape and unescape Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions)

Онлайн-енкодер:
[Encoding html using javascript's escape & unescape](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/html/encode.html)